# Can we monitor the weblogic logs of more than one host in kibana using ELK stack and File Beat?

Tags: elasticsearch, weblogic

I want to monitor more than one hosts weblogic logs with ELK stack and FileBeat? Is it possible?

please help me in doing this, If anyone already done this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is absolutely possible. Filebeat will add in host information to the data it sends to Elasticsearch, so you'll be able to search/filter/aggregate logs by host, among other dimensions.